# Using the specific id based off the hyperlink to target which id to fetch results

Tags: mysql, wordpress

tried to pull by using query off $player_id and nothing worked.

```
$player_id =$playerary[2];
/* echo 'player_id='.$player_id; */
global $wpdb;

/* Query to pull info from (players) along with player's id */
$pinfo = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM players WHERE player_id =  $player_id"); 
print_r($pinfo);
/* $fn = $pinfo['first_name']; */
echo "<h3>".$pinfo->first_name."</h3>";
```

Comment: use `player_id =  '$player_id'`

Comment: $pinfo = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM players WHERE player_id = '$player_id'); <-- that didnt work either

Comment: is it echoed player_id `//                      echo 'player_id='.$player_id;`

Comment: Is there a SQL error? If so what? Is `$player_id` a number or a string identifier? Can it contain quotes? Is this enforced?